# Clustering of (mostly) spatial data, with "un-mergeable" constraints

Tags: clustering, spatial, metric

I have data from field surveys, each representing the location of a bird,
together with a date. I need to cluster the data based on distance (eg. < 120m).

However, there are further constraints: There is a categorical variable called
"singing", that can be 0 or 1. If two points A and B both have singing=1, and A
and B have the same date, they must not be in the same cluster, even if they
are spatially close.

What algorithm applies to this situation?

I don't know much about spatial clustering, but naïvely I thought that I'd just
compute the metric distances, and then for any two points A, B as above, I'd
set their distance to +∞, and then use a standard clustering technique.
However, it's not clear to me that this is a metric in any obvious sense,
because A and B can be far from each other but both close to a third point C (I guess it's a *semimetric*),
and I don't know how to use this idea in practice.

I'm working with R, but could also switch to a different language to solve this
problem.

PS: let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. If $d(A,B) = 99999$ then ($d(A,C) = 1$ and $d(B,C) = 1$) violates the triangle inequality.

Comment: If you use farthest neighbour (=complete) linkage in hierarchical clustering then your setting of some distances to a big value will effectively do, it will preclude combining the "prohibited for pairing" points in one cluster (except for the very last steps of the agglomeration, but you will not be interested in those steps). Farthest neighbour, like nearest neighbour linkage, needs no metricity and it does not calculate on distances, so the big value won't meddle.

Comment: thank you ttnphns, using the `hclust` with the `"complete"` method from R's GeoSphere package I got my solution to work.